# Looping with Q promises in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm very new to js and node coming from a java world. I threw a test program together based on the real program I'm writing.  It's using the Q library in a node.js program.

The for loop is only acting on the last item in the array.. it's like all the other Q.promises are lost.

My output is:
registerELB
de-registerELB
resumeASG 4
started instance 4
resumeASG 4
started instance 4
resumeASG 4
started instance 4
resumeASG 4
started instance 4
autoshutdown complete.

Where as I expect it to be:

resumeASG 1
started instance 1
resumeASG 2
started instance 2
resumeASG 3
started instance 3
resumeASG 4
started instance 4
registerELB
de-registerELB
autoshutdown complete.

1. what's going on in the loop?  Are the promises getting lost?
2. why is registerELB and de-registerELB happening before my first .then()

   var Q = require('q');
       var startedInstances = [];

   ```
   test();

   function test() {
       getInstances()
       .then(function(data) {
           var promise = Q.defer();

           for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
               var somedata = data[x];
               console.log(somedata);

               startOrStop(somedata)
               .then(function (updateStatus) {
                   var promiseinner = Q.defer();
                   console.log(somedata);
                   if(updateStatus == 'start') {
                       return Q.nfcall(resumeASG, somedata)
                       .then(Q.nfcall(startInstance, somedata));
                   } else if(updateStatus == 'stop') { 
                       return Q.nfcall(suspendASG, somedata)
                       .then(Q.nfcall(stopInstance, somedata));
                   }
                   promiseinner.resolve('complete');

                   return promiseinner.promise;
               })
           }
           promise.resolve('successful');

           return promise.promise;

       }, function(error) {
           console.log('Failed to get instance data ' + error);
           //context.fail();
       }).then(function(data) {
           return registerELB();
       }, function(error) {
           console.log('Failed to Re-register ELB ' + error);
           //context.fail();
       }).then(function(data) {
           console.log('autoshutdown complete.')
           //context.succeed(data);
       }, function(error) {
           console.log('autoshutdown failed to complete. ' + error)
           //context.fail();
       }).done();
   };

   function getInstances() {
       var promise = Q.defer();

       startedInstances.push(1);
       startedInstances.push(2);
       startedInstances.push(3);
       startedInstances.push(4);

       promise.resolve(startedInstances);
       return promise.promise;
   }

   function suspendASG (asg) {
       var promise = Q.defer();

       console.log('suspendASG ' + asg);
       promise.resolve(asg);

       return promise.promise;
   }

   function resumeASG (asg) {
       var promise = Q.defer();

       console.log('resumeASG ' + asg);
       promise.resolve(asg);

       return promise.promise;
   }

   function registerELB() {
       var promise  = Q.defer();

       console.log('registerELB ');
       console.log('de-registerELB ');
       promise.resolve('success elb');

       return promise.promise;
   }

   function startInstance(instanceId) {
       var promise = Q.defer();

       console.log('started instance ' + instanceId);
       promise.resolve(instanceId);

       return promise.promise;
   }

   function stopInstance(instanceId) {
   var promise = Q.defer();

       console.log('stopped instance ' + instanceId);
       promise.resolve(instanceId);

       return promise.promise;
   }

   function startOrStop (instance) {
       var promise = Q.defer();


       promise.resolve('start');

       return promise.promise;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic issue with a `for` loop and any async operation inside the loop.  Because your async operations inside the `for` loop complete some time LATER after the `for` loop has already finished, any variables set inside your `for` loop will have the values at the end of the loop when any of your async operations completes.

In your particular case, the `somedata` variable is a problem here.  You can generally work-around this issue by using a closure so that each invocation of your async operations has it's own function and thus it's own state that uniquely survives until the async operation has completed.

It looks to me like you may also have other synchronization issues going on here since your `for` loop is running all your operations in parallel and you have no link between your inner async operations and the outer promise you are resolving, so I suspect there are other problems here too.

But, if you just change your `for` loop to a `.forEach()` loop, then each invocation of the loop will have it's own unique state.  I honestly can't say that there aren't other issues in this code (since I have no way of testing it), but this should at least solve one issue related to the `for` loop:

```
test();

function test() {
    getInstances()
    .then(function(data) {
        var promise = Q.defer();

        // -------- Change made here -------------
        // change for loop to .forEach() loop here
        // to create closure so your async operations
        // each can access their own data
        data.forEach(function(somedata) {
            console.log(somedata);

            startOrStop(somedata)
            .then(function (updateStatus) {
                var promiseinner = Q.defer();
                console.log(somedata);
                if(updateStatus == 'start') {
                    return Q.nfcall(resumeASG, somedata)
                    .then(Q.nfcall(startInstance, somedata));
                } else if(updateStatus == 'stop') { 
                    return Q.nfcall(suspendASG, somedata)
                    .then(Q.nfcall(stopInstance, somedata));
                }
                promiseinner.resolve('complete');

                return promiseinner.promise;
            })
        });
        promise.resolve('successful');

        return promise.promise;

    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Failed to get instance data ' + error);
        //context.fail();
    }).then(function(data) {
        return registerELB();
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Failed to Re-register ELB ' + error);
        //context.fail();
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log('autoshutdown complete.')
        //context.succeed(data);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('autoshutdown failed to complete. ' + error)
        //context.fail();
    }).done();
};
```

Also, do you realize that your inner promises (inside the `.forEach()` loop) are not linked at all to the outer promise?  So, `getInstances()` will resolve its promise, long before the inner promises in the `.forEach()` loop are done?  This looks broken to me.  I don't know exactly what to recommend because I don't know which operations you want to run in parallel and which should be in series.  You may need to do a `Promise.all()` that collects all the promises from the `for` loop and then use that to resolve your outer promise.

Comment: @mhunts46 -  since it looks like you may be new here, if you get an answer to your question, then you can indicate that to the community by checking the green checkmark to the left of the best answer. This will earn both you and the person who provided the answer some reputation points which can lead to more privileges on the site